Connection to container works but Intellisense and Debugger doesnt recognize it
I have a connection to a container (apptainer) and can select it as python interpreter which then starts the container and executes the code. That works. However when I want to start a debugger session in VSCode it is not recognized. The intellisense also doesnt seem to recognize it in general. Does someone know whats going on or what I should do?
Thanks for your time and help
Tried to start a debugging session with the python interpreter that uses my container but that doesnt work and is not recognized
